# How to inclue 2 validators in the same formbuilder using angular8 reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

one is password and the other one is account number, both of them have each input extra as confirm password and confirm account number. I have used reactive forms and is as follows:

TS:

```
private initAchForm() {
      this.achInfoForm = this.FB.group({
        password: ['',Validators.required],
        confirmpassword: ['',Validators.required],
        accountNumber: [null,Validators.required],
        reAccountNumber: [null,Validators.required],
      },
      { validator: ConfirmRoutingValidator.MatchPassword});
  }
```

have created one file which contains these custom things:

password match file;

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
export class ConfirmPasswordValidator {
  static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
    let password = control.get('password').value;
    let confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword').value;
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ ConfirmPassword: true });
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

export class ConfirmAccountValidator {
  static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
    let password = control.get('accountNumber').value;
    let confirmPassword = control.get('reAccountNumber').value;
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      control.get('reAccountNumber').setErrors({ ConfirmPassword: true });
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to add 2 validators in one section, like  `{ validator: ConfirmRoutingValidator.MatchPassword}, { validator: ConfirmAccountValidator.MatchPassword}` but get an error as 
`Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.`

How can this be solved? I tried adding these values in the control names but it says value of undefined because it is not able to get those values.

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide them in array, i.e.:

```
password: ['', [Validators.required, yourCustomValidator]]
```

Comment: thanks for response i tried this as well but it throws error as value is undefined

Comment: ok, so maybe try to use `Validators.compose()` and put this array as it's parameter

Comment: reRoutingNumber: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ConfirmRoutingValidator.MatchPassword])],

Comment: something like that?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni finally I've found why you're getting `value of null` error, your declaration has field named `resetpassword`, but in your validator you're using `resetPassword` with uppercase `P` and that's why it doesn't see this control value

Comment: no sorry, i have gave here wrong but in my code it is proper, i am trying to create demo for that

Comment: i have created demo but something is wrong https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s147j4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts